# In this sentence, what does "being seen as somehow sinful" modify?

Tags: sentence-construction, modifiers

I was reading a PDF on [Linguahouse about Netflix](https://www.linguahouse.com/de/esl-lesson-plans/general-english/netflix-ing) when I came across this part:

> Many point to how television used to be a shared experience: a topic of discussion at work, a meeting of everyone in the family for the latest,  weekly episode of a sitcom or soap opera. Now, Netflix has brought in the era of binge-watching: individuals greedily consuming the whole series of programmes or films in one sitting. Defenders, however, would say that the diversity Netflix allows and promotes wasn't present in shows of old. Equally, no one would complain if you read a novel in one sitting, or read several poems in one go. **Is there a certain cultural snobbery around doing the same with a film or programme being seen as somehow sinful?**

In this sentence, what does "being seen as somehow sinful" modify? I think it modifies "cultural snobbery" but I'm not too sure.

Also, I had trouble understanding what the sentence means in general and the role of "being seen as somehow sinful" in the sentence.

Comment: **What PDF**? That link just brings up the Linguahouse home page. It appears that it is 'doing the same' (whatever that is) with a film that would be seen as somehow sinful. Why don't you show enough of the preceding text so we can decide?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey "Doing the same" here means doing the equivalent to reading a book in one sitting, but to a film, in other words, watching a whole movie in one sitting.

Comment: Presumably 'watching a film in one sitting', though I don't know who regards that as 'somehow sinful' - surely a feature film is meant to be watched in one sitting?

Comment: The bolded text is difficult to understand.  I think most native English speakers would find it poorly written at best. I suspect the author thinks that obscure is good.

Comment: Listen up@justAnewb stands with Ukraine. I suggest you answer the question that Michael Harvey posted an hour ago.

Comment: @gotube - yes, that's what I immediately thought as well, but, as Kate Bunting says, that's what people normally do with films, so thinking it culturally 'sinful' seems a little silly. I have had a thought (but this might be answering a poor-quality question): maybe the original writer was thinking about [binge-watching](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/binge-watch) a TV series? I know some people have got snooty about that in the past.

Comment: @BillOnne - regarding the original writer,  my practice is not to attribute to intent that which can be adequately explained by stupidity.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I followed the same chain of thought, that the snobbery doesn't really apply to watching movies, while it does apply to bingeing TV series. But since it wasn't at all a question about that content, and the English learning question applied regardless, I didn't bother wading in.

Comment: The word "equally" suggests there is something else before this which is relevant and being compared with reading a book or watching a film. If so, this question is impossible to answer.

Comment: Please provide proper attribution for the text that you quote.  That means title, author, and publication, or as many of those as are available. If the source is long, such as a book, please include a page number or other location also. If the source is online, please include a link also. See [**Marking and Attributing Examples, Sources, and Other Quotes**](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5785/91457)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a certain cultural snobbery around doing the same with a film or programme being seen as somehow sinful?

The sentence is just very badly constructed.

It should be:

"Is there a certain cultural snobbery around doing the same with a film or programme, it being seen as somehow sinful?"

or

"Is there a certain cultural snobbery around doing the same with a film or programme? Is it seen as somehow sinful?"

As has been mentioned in comments, this sentence makes no sense for a single film, but might do if it was a series.

e.g. "Is it seen as sinful to watch all the Star Wars films at one sitting?"

(No, but it might make your eyes bleed.)